# how do I slice a numpy array using an array of 1d positions

Tags: python, numpy

consider the arrays `a` and `b`

```
a = np.arange(25).reshape(5, -1)
b = np.array([4, 2, 3, 0, 1])
```

How do I slice `a` using `b` to get these elements?

[image]

---

I can use a list comprehension

```
np.array([a[i, b[i]] for i in range(5)])

array([ 4,  7, 13, 15, 21])
```

But I wanted a pure numpy solution

Comment: @Divakar thanks for pointing that out.  I had a heck of a time finding the right search terms.

Comment: Yeah also I wish I had a direct dup one to offer, but it's sort of chained into 1D and 2D variants.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> a[np.arange(5), b]
array([ 4,  7, 13, 15, 21])
```

When indices are arrays, they are interpreted element-wise, following [broadcasting rules](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Comment: Performancewise, is there a difference between `a[range(5), b]` and `a[np.arange(5), b]`?

Comment: Good point: using ``np.arange`` will be faster because it creates the index array more directly. I'll edit the answer (though ``range()`` does work)

Comment: Jup, thought so: an `arange` is contiguous in memory and can be iterated over at numpy speeds. A `range` is either non-contiguous in memory (Python 2) or an object that on the fly generates values (Python 3). Both are most likely slower.

Comment: Timings suggest that `a[xrange(n),b]` is the same as `a[np.array(xrange(n)), b]`.  So `arange` is faster because it generates the values directly.